# Parallel universe and Infinite monkey theorem

Tags: cosmology, universe, probability, multiverse

Is the [Infinite monkey theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) helpful for determining the existence of the very same our universe somewhere else?

Comment: I've once read a popular article wherein serious cosmologists were applying this theorem (although the name was not explicitely mentioned) to investigate if things we can observe inside our cosmic horizon could be repeated in our universe outside the cosmic horizon. I think when considering the question in such a context, it is legitimate and does not need to be closed. But maybe @Inquisitive you could clarify the context a little bit?

Comment: This is rather open-ended in its current form. (as well as being about fictional physics, and not really clear) Please see the don't ask section of the [faq#dontask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Well, not really, though some amusement can be had by calculating how far you'd have to go to find an exact copy of your mother in law. However these calculations are not based on any rigorous science, so while they're fun take care with them.

The basic idea is that if you take some system (e.g. your mother in law) containing $n$ Planck volumes then the maximum number of configurations of this system is 2$^n$. So you need to look at about 2$^n$ such volumes to stand a reasonable chance of finding a duplicate of your mother in law. This is the origin of claims that an exact copy of the Earth must exist if you take a big enough region of the universe. Whether such claims have any physical validity is open to debate.

Comment: John Rennie - Consider a universe of size 1cm^2 with only 1 atom(consider an atom as an indivisible particle) ,now doesn't that 1 atom has infinite number of possible arrangements?1)Due to the infinite number of possible orientation of atom. 2)Infinite number of possible arrangement of atom in the space? Planck volumes are something related to that? (I understood what you have written above except what means of Planck volumes)

Comment: @Inquisitive quantum particles have only a limited number of possible orientations in the space. For an atom I think there are only 2 possible orientations. Similarly atom has only limited possibilities of being placed in a volume, and I am quite sure it is much less than the number of Plank volumes in the space (what you actually have to know is the number of energy levels in such volume). Yet the number cannot be greater than the number of the Planck volumes.

Comment: @Anixx: "Similarly atom has only limited possibilities of being placed in a volume". How this is true? Each and every points except few from the edges in the above mentioned universe can act as the center of atom. So infinite number of possiblilities.

Comment: @Inquisitive: the idea is (remember this is all very speculative) that it isn't possible to measure position to an accuracy of better than a Planck length. Therefore the number of physically distinct positions for your atom is 1cm divided by the Planck length.

Comment: There is a related concept that says that although entropy is an increasing quantity, a finite system will eventually find its way back through an initial state within a poincaire recurrence time.  Nevertheless, when applied to systems like "the universe", such timescales are inconceivably long.

Comment: @Inquisitive no. The walls create an interference pattern inside the volume which is the wave function solution. The number of such solutions is limited. An analogy is the position of an electron in an atom: it cannot occupy any orbit, but only just the permitted ones. This is the basics of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Inquisitive Yes there are continuum variables defining most systems, and yes, mathematically, you can never hope duplicate such things with a finite number of samples. However, John Rennie is implicitly constructing large equivalence classes of systems. If you jiggle all the atoms in your body by some random amount on the order of a Plank length, it really won't make you a different person in any conceivable way.